# Python regex words boundary with unexpected results

Tags: python, regex, word-boundary

```
import re
sstring = "ON Any ON Any"
regex1 = re.compile(r''' \bON\bANY\b''', re.VERBOSE)
regex2 = re.compile(r'''\b(ON)?\b(Any)?''', re.VERBOSE)
regex3 = re.compile(r'''\b(?:ON)?\b(?:Any)?''', re.VERBOSE)
for a in regex1.findall(sstring): print(a)
print("----------")
for a in regex2.findall(sstring): print(a)
print("----------")
for a in regex3.findall(sstring): print(a)
print("----------")
```

> ---
>
> ('ON', '')
>   ('', '')
>   ('', 'Any')
>   ('', '')
>   ('ON', '')
>   ('', '')
>   ('', 'Any')
>
> ### ('', '')
>
> ON
>
> Any
>
> ON
>
> Any
>
> ---

Having read many articles on the internet and S.O. I think I still don't understand the regex word boundary: `\b`

The first regex doesn't give me the expected result I think it's must give me "ON Any On Any" but it still not give me that.

The second regex gives me tuples and I don't know why or understand the meaning of: ('', '')

The third regex gives prints the results on separated lines and empty lines in betweens

Could you please help me to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to match `ON ANY` you need to add an escaped (since you are using `re.VERBOSE` flag) space between `ON` and `ANY` as `\b` word boundary *being a **zero-width assertion*** does not consume any text, just asserts a position between specific characters. That is the reason for your first `re.compile(r''' \bON\bANY\b''', re.VERBOSE)` approach failure.

Use

```
rx = re.compile(r''' \bON\ ANY\b ''', re.VERBOSE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cBsGLd)

The `re.compile(r'''\b(ON)?\b(Any)?''', re.VERBOSE)` returns tuples since you defined `(...)` *capturing groups* in the pattern.

The `re.compile(r'''\b(?:ON)?\b(?:Any)?''', re.VERBOSE)` matches optional sequences, either `ON` or `Any`, so you get those words as values. You get empty values as well because this regex can match just a word boundary (all other subpatterns are optional).

More details about word boundaries:

- [Word boundaries at *Regular-Expressions.info*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- [Java Regex Word Boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389837/java-regex-word-boundaries) (this is still a word boundary in a regex, also applicable here)

Comment: There are a lot of cases when `\b` is helpful. Surely it is not a universal remedy, and `re.UNICODE` is sometimes necessary, or even `(?<!\S)`/`(?!\S)` lookarounds can turn out better alternatives, but the main point is that it does not move the regex index. If you have a space, match it.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor I think my misunderstanding was that I couldn't imagine a useful usage for \b in case of I have to write the the white-space between "ON" and "Any", But with Example like that I'm now imagine it may be useful sometimes, regex is `\bON\b` and search strings are `ON#Any` or `ON!Any` But in my in my first regex `"\bON\bAny"` I have to write the white-space since \b is zero-width length

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and still learning about its formatting, so I deleted the comment more than one time to write it correctly

But I would thank your for your appreciated support