# Why is "\b" not catching my word boundary in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, word-boundary

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to match an expression and take advantage of the word boundary expression because there may be a space, arbitrary number of spaces, or a dash between my words.  But this isn’t working

```
2.3.0 :006 > /first\bsecond/.match('first second')
 => nil
```

The manual here — https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html suggests that “\b” is the right expression to use to catch word boundaries so I’m wondering where I’m going wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875620/python-regex-words-boundary-with-unexpected-results/39876126#39876126. `\b` is not matching whitespaces and there is one between `first` and `second`.

Comment: `\b` is usually used at the beginning or end of an expression only since its utility in other places is questionable.

Comment: @tadman there's a chance that `\b` can be useful in the middle of an expression, but it's so rare that I can't think of a real world use case. Something like this is an efficient use: `/[a-z ]\b[a-z ]/`

Comment: @Sam Yeah, the cases of using it in the middle are typically more like `/test\b|thing/` but in those cases they're at the beginning or end of a sub-expression.

Comment: This appears to be a pure-Ruby question. If so, there should be no Rails tag. Keep in mind that some members may filter out questions with Rails tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` matches a zero-length word boundary, not a space. You're looking for something more like this:

```
/first\b.\bsecond/.match('first second')
```

This will match any character (`.`) in between `first` and `second`, as long as there is a word boundary on either side.

---

However, this is not how word boundaries are usually used (since there is no need to use a zero-length check when you are matching the word boundary itself). `\b` is essentially looking for a non-word character after a word character; so, instead, you could just look for a non-word character in-between the `t` in `first` and `s` in `second`:

```
/first\Wsecond/.match('first second')
```

This is exactly the same as the first example...but, realistically, you probably just want to match whitespace and can use something like this:

```
/first\ssecond/.match('first second')
```

---

@WiktorStribiżew's third example shows the best use of word boundaries (at the beginning and end). This is because you aren't matching anything before or after, so a zero-length test is helpful. Otherwise, the above examples could match something like `first secondary`. In the end, I'd use an expression like:

```
/\bfirst\ssecond\b/.match('first second')
```

Comment: Or `/first\ssecond/` or `/first second/` or `/\bfirst second\b/`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I was just updating the question to explain why you wouldn't usually use a zero-length match in a situation like this.

Comment: Thanks but the answer given fails for the case /first\Wsecond/.match('first  second') in whcih there is more than one space in between the words.

Comment: @Dave any of these examples can make use of the `+` modifier to say "one or more", i.e. `/first\W+second/`...