# How to understand regex '\b'?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am learning the regex.But I can't understand the '\b' , match a word boundary  . there have three situation,like this:

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

I can't understand the third situation.for example：

```
var reg = /end\bend/g;
var string = 'wenkend,end,end,endend';
alert( reg.test(string) ) ; //false
```

The '\b' require a '\w' character at its one side , another not '\w' character at the other side . the string 'end,end' should match the rule, after the first character is string ',' , before the last character is string ',' , so why the result is error .Could you help,Thanks in advance!

============dividing line=============

With your help, I understand it. the 'end,end' match  the first 'end' and have a boundary ,but the next character is ',' not 'e',so '/end\bend' is false.

In other words ,the reg '/end\bend/g' or others similar reg aren't exit forever.
Thanks again

Comment: `\b` does not capture anything

Comment: Your regex should be `/end\b,\bend/g`

Comment: `\b` doesn't match a character, it matches a spot between characters, a boundary. It's impossible for there to be a word boundary there when the two characters beside the `\b` are both word characters. The regex you're perhaps thinking of is `/end\Wend/g`

Comment: Use the regex `reg = /end\b|\bend/g;`

Comment: I know the '\b' capture noting , just a boundary,so the 'end,end' should match,because the ',' just a boundary.@Steve

Comment: @Anan: The comma is not a boundary. There are boundaries immediately before and after the comma, but the comma itself is not a boundary.

Comment: A comma is not a boundary. The boundary is the null-width substring between `d` and `,`.

Comment: i think u should refer this link http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @Jan: Explaining a word boundary using lookarounds is like potty-training by using OSHA manuals. I don't think it's very useful :P

Comment: so it's mean the reg /end\bend/g or others similar reg isn't exist forever ?@4castle

Comment: @Anan Right, `/end\bend/` can't match anything, because it would match `endend`, but then there isn't a word boundary between the middle `de`, so the match fails.

Comment: @Amadan: Turned the potty-training into a full answer :)

Comment: Ok,I don't really want to use /end\Wend/g, I just want to  understand the \b.I understand now.thanks very much :)@4castle

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875620/python-regex-words-boundary-with-unexpected-results/39876126#39876126

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\b` matches position, not a character. So this regex `/end\bend/g` says that there must be string `end`. Then it should be followed by not a word character, which is `,` and it matches, but the regex engine doesn't move in the string and it stays at `,`. So the next character in your regex is `e`, and `e` doesn't match `,`. So regexp fails. Here is step by step what happens:

```
-----------------
/end\bend/g,   "end,end"        (match)
   |              |
-----------------

/end\bend/g,   "end,end"        (both regex and string position moved - match)
     |             |
------------------

/end\bend/g,   "end,end"        (the previous match was zero-length, so only regex position moved - not match)
      |            |
```

Answer (score 4):

With (most) regular expression engines, you can **match**, **capture** characters and **assert** positions within a string.

For the purpose of this example let's assume the string

```
Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
```

where you want to match the character `o` (which is there twice, after `R` and after `t`). Now you want to specify the *position*  and want to match `o`s only before lowercase `r`s.
You write (with a positive lookahead):

```
o(?=r)
```

Now generalize the idea of **zero-width assertions** where you want to look for a word character *ahead* while making sure there's no word character immediately behind. Herefore you could write:

```
(?=\w)(?<!\w)
```

A positive and a negative lookahead, combined. We're almost there :) You only need the same thing around (a word character behind and **not** a word character ahead) which is:

```
(?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

If you combine these two, you'll eventually get (see the `|` in the middle):

```
(?:(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

---

Which is equivalent to `\b` (and a lot longer). Coming back to our string, this is true for:

```
 Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
 # right before R
 # right after e in Rogue
 # right before O of One
 # right after e of One (: is not a word character)
 # and so on...
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0iaBYD/1).

---

To conclude, you can think of `\b` as a **zero-width assertion** which only ensures a position within the string.

Comment: FYI, [tchrist's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4215293/3832970) also describes that "conditional" (actually, contextual) word boundary behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Expression

```
/(end)\b|\b(end)/g
```

Comment: To get a clear idea about how Regular Expression is Working

Comment: The goal here isn't to hand them a fish, it's to teach the person how to fish. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: That's why i posted website link from where i have understand Regular Expression...

Comment: She can try Everything related to RE over there

Comment: Right, those links are certainly helpful in learning regex, but your answer is not helpful. It's a signpost that says, *"the answer is hidden away over here --->"*