# Regex that matches "hello @c" but not "hello @cat"

Tags: regex

When trying to parse a string a string for mentions I was using this regex: `.*@${username}.*` where `${username}` is a parameter.

if `${username} = 'c'`

then this becomes `.*@c.*`
so this will incorrectly match something like `hello @cat`.

I need a regex that **matches the entire string**:

```
@c
hello @c
@c hello
hello @c hello
```

and does not match:

```
@cat
```

- It doesn't have to be one regex. It could be multiple ones that cover all cases without interfering with another case.

Comment: This seems to work: `(^|\s)@c(\s|$)`.  Probably a bunch of better ways to do it, not a regex guru.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match entire words only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only)

Comment: @JJJ problem with \b is the `@` character, so it's not the same question

Comment: @Tibrogargan Why would that make any difference?

Comment: @JJJ The answer you linked uses \b (and/or \w) to delimit the term (a word) being searched for, but the problem is that @ is not a word character so there is not boundary before or after it.  The term is not a word.

Comment: @Tibrogargan The OP is interested only in the ending of the word. Surely they have the common sense to adapt the duplicate to their code (`@c\b`).

Comment: @Tibrogargan I appreciate the effort!
JJJ: Thanks! I just learned the term "word boundary" from this. Sorry for duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

`.*@\bc\b.*`

https://regex101.com/r/OYjmvQ/1

I was also wondering why it wasn't working in my actual code though (Java) and derp: [Java Regex Word Boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389837/java-regex-word-boundaries)

had to be double escaped:

```
.*@\\bc\\b.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the user name is not followed by a username constituant: `@$username\([^a-z]\|$\)`. Note that depending on the regexp parser you might need to remove the backslashes.